# Swift WidgetKit Speedometer Widget - Location Returning Null

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, core-location, widgetkit

I want the speedometer to update as quickly as possible but I don't know how to set up the class or getTimeline function to do so. The permissions are all correct because i sometimes get a speed for a short time then it returns to the default set value. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Heres my code:

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import Intents
import CoreLocation
import Foundation


struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

        var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        var location: CLLocation?

        override init() {
            super.init()
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()

            let _ = print("Location Manager Init")
        }

        func requestUpdate(_ completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
            self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
        }

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            guard let location = locations.last else { return }
            self.location = location
        }

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    

    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: ConfigurationIntent(), locManager: Provider.LocationManager.init())
    }

    func getSnapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: configuration, locManager: Provider.LocationManager.init())
        completion(entry)
    }
    
    func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []

        let currentDate = Date()
        for offset in 0 ..< 20 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: offset, to: currentDate)!
            let locManager = Provider.LocationManager.init()
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, configuration: configuration, locManager: locManager)
            entries.append(entry)
        }

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}


struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let configuration: ConfigurationIntent
    let locManager: Provider.LocationManager
}


struct SpeedometerEntryView : View {
    @Environment(\.widgetFamily) var widgetFamily
    
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    
    var displaySpeed: Text {
        var speed: Double = (entry.locManager.location?.speed ?? Double(30.8458)) * 2.237
        
        if speed < 0 {
            speed = speed * -1
        }
        
        let intSpeed: Int = Int(speed)
        return Text(intSpeed.formatted())
    }
    
    var gaugeValue: Double {
        var speed: Double = (entry.locManager.location?.speed ?? Double(30.8458)) * 2.237 / 100
        
        if speed > 1 {
            speed = 1
        }
        
        else if speed < 0 {
            speed = speed * -1
        }
        
        return speed
    }
        
    var body: some View {
        
        Gauge(
            value: gaugeValue,
            label: {Text("MPH")},
            currentValueLabel: {displaySpeed}
        )
        .gaugeStyle(.accessoryCircular)
        
    }
}


struct Speedometer: Widget {
    
    let kind: String = "Speedometer"
    
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            SpeedometerEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Speed Widget")
        .description("Current Speed")
        .supportedFamilies([.accessoryCircular])
    }
}
```

Comment: Widgets are metered you only get a certain number of updates a day and Apple can decrease at any time. I think the average was once every 15 minutes.

Comment: This sounds more like a Live Activity than a Widget. Either way, you are going to be limited. Things like this suck power out of a battery, so Apple limits these things.